# permissions issue for one user on a external drive

Tags: command-line, external-hard-drive, file-permissions

I am having issues with permissions and I got this cmd from a different user and it doesnt seem to work to help give me full control how do I do that

I am logged in as the adminstrator so I typed CACLS "D:\Documents and Settings\Lynn\My Documents*.* /e /g:*Adminstrator* F /s and I get the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: See https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/utils/ci/tip/tree/win/uac/  for solution.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/353739/have-issue-with-access-denied-invalid-descriptor-and-external-storage-for-w for some related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CACLS "D:\Documents and Settings\Lynn\My **Documents*.*** /e /g:Adminstrator F /s

Your command (above) is missing a backslash.

Make sure D: is the correct drive letter for the mounted drive, of course. Also, I believe there should be a colon between the user (Administrator) and the new permission (F).

So, something like this might work?

**CACLS "D:\Documents and Settings\Lynn\My Documents*.* /e /g:Adminstrator:F /s**

Comment: still getting the same issue, I think I am just going to give up

Comment: weird ... just noticed that Superuser removed the backslash I added to the command above ... anyway, the issue might be w/ your path. your command correctly includes a beginning quotation, but I'm not seeing an ending quotation (which should be at teh end of the path but before the cmd line arguments)

Comment: definitely don't give up! you're so close to a resolution, it would be a shame to give up now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my scripts for automating this task:

https://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/utils/ci/tip/tree/win/uac/

Put both script to directory and run **uac.js**.

For all hierarchy belong this directory scripts restore ownership and grand full access for All.